# Javascript draw directions when take data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-maps

*This is a very basic question but please help becouse I try to solve this 3 days and I dont have any answer. I try many solutions but again is the same.*

Here I have a nArray functions which return me a bigArray JSON, which contain objects so like this:
**`bigArray`**

```
  Array[5]
    0: Object
    1: Object
         DISTANCE_FROM_PREVIOUS_OBJECT_LOCATION: 2.087970147789207
         lat: "48.866588"
         leftPosition: 183
         lng: "2.309037999999987"
         topPosition: 57
            __proto__: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

So here I have "n" number of object. All objects contain lat and lng.

I try to solve my problem with basic google example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vz52/3/
but here i have a problem how to change `<option value` in google example with my JSON(lat,lng) data from my code.

I try this code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

but I don't know where and how to put my JSON (lat,lng) data and to draw multiple directions on map.

How I can show directions in map with coordinates in my objects?

**UPDATE: The google code not neccesary must be this (you can put some other google code example and integrate with my json), I just need a solution to draw direction based on my JSON array**

Answer (score 1):

You can put the latitude and longitude in the start value separated by a comma. Google accepts that as well as putting any search in there.

So you have something like:

```
var start = lat + ',' + lng;
```

If you need to change the option value on the fly you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('start').value = lat + ',' + lng;
```

Comment: Do you want to change the select options on-the-fly with a JSON response?

Comment: I just want to draw direction beetween points based on my json data, so you can change google code as you want

Answer (score 1):

The [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) spec says

- origin (required) specifies the start location from which to
  calculate directions. This value may either be specified as a String
  (e.g. "Chicago, IL") or as a LatLng value.
- destination (required) specifies the end location to which to
  calculate directions. This value may either be specified as a String 
  (e.g. "Chicago, IL") or as a LatLng value.

so valid request origin or destination value may be like "Bondi Beach" or "-33.890542,151.274856" (Example)

following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8wgC/) demonstrates situation much like yours.

here given data,

```
var latLngs = [{
    name: 'Bondi Beach',
    lat: -33.890542,
    lng: 151.274856
}, {
    name: 'Coogee Beach',
    lat: -33.923036,
    lng: 151.259052
}, {
    name: 'Cronulla Beach',
    lat: -34.028249,
    lng: 151.157507
}, {
    name: 'Manly Beach',
    lat: -33.80010128657071,
    lng: 151.28747820854187
}, {
    name: 'Maroubra Beach',
    lat: -33.950198,
    lng: 151.259302
}];
```

**EDIT**

you can use the way points in the direction service for multiple linked routes.

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8wgC/1/)

hope this helps.

Comment: this is not the answer, you just copy google example, where is here multiple distance route

Comment: Maybe i did not not understand your question. what do you mean by "multiple distance route"? do you want to plot all possible routes between locations pairs?

Comment: yes this help, but I'm limited with waypoints to 8 waipoints, so what if I have more than 8 waypoints. Is there any other solution for this limit?

Comment: I need to use this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#usage_limits_and_requirements but how o integrate  with my array?

Answer (score 1):

```
here is short example: 

      function calculateDistances() {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      for (var a=0; a<=length.array; a++){
      service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
          origins: [arr[1][1], arr[1][2]],
          destinations: [arr[1][3], arr[1][4]],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
       }
}
```

full tutorial is : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is helpful for you

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

you need only start and end point no need to draw with all points. And you want then you need to attach path in many pieces like from first point to second and attach it with other next one and so on untill the last point connect ... so i think it is the google facility you just draw between two points first and last.

Another way is polyline but it is not good for driving route it is better for flight routes... hope you understand. gud luck

Comment: I need to use this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#usage_limits_and_requirements but how o integrate  with my array?

Comment: with the help of for loop just take one array keep all lat long values in that and then run this function with for loop calculateDistances() use for loop inside this function. Here is full example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Answer (score 0):

here is the fiddle I have created with data given by "shakib" 
[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SSqFr/)
.
may it will solve your needs.
although if you need to display marker on way points you can do it by,

```
        function addDirection(){

            if(i < yourLatLongs.length -1){
              var start = yourLatLongs[i].lat+","+yourLatLongs[i].lng;
              var end = yourLatLongs[i+1].lat+","+yourLatLongs[i+1].lng;

             var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(yourLatLongs[i].lat,yourLatLongs[i].lng);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            }); 

              calcRoute(start,end);
              console.log(i);
              i++;
            }
        }
```